# Strange behavior for Spyder code annotations

Tags: python, ide, editor, spyder

Using comments such as `#TIPS` and `#HINTS` will render a blue checkmark in the Spyder IDE like this:

[image]

If you go to <kbd>Tools|Editor|Code Introspection/Analysis</kbd> and activate <kbd>Code Annotations (TODO, FIXME, XXX, HINT, TIP...)</kbd>, those keywords do not seem to trigger any effect in the SPyder IDE at all:

[image]

I would assume that `HINT` and `TIP` should render the checkmark and not `HINTS` and `TIPS`.

Does anyone know if it is supposed to be like this?

Thank you!

**My system:**

Windows 7, 64 bit

Python 3.6.0

IPython 5.1.0

Spyder 3.2.5

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This looks like a bug. Please report it in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! An issue has been posted on the issue tracker as requested.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do it!

Comment: That's the absolute least I could do regarding how brilliant Spyder is!!

Comment: Writing something like  "# !!!" triggers this in my Spyder too